# Install Wordpress Backup with New Fresh Database

Tags: wordpress

I had a website made in wordpress. The database is now corrupt, cannot be restored and I dont have a copy of the database either. However I have a copy of the website folder contents that I made when I installed wordpress. I want to use the same copied files to reinstall the website with a new(fresh) database so that I dont have to go through the whole process of psd to wordpress conversion and all. Is there a way out possible?

Regards.

Comment: You wont be able to restore the website with out the database backup. check if your service provider does automatic backups by month or week. Most providers do that. The database hold your posts, pages and many other settings. It will be hard to recreate if there were a lot of content for the website.

Answer (score 1):

Delete (drop) all the the site's DB's tables through PhpMyAdmin or mysql CLI, then go to your site url and repeat the install process.

[wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) has a nice builtin cli tool for doing this: `wp db reset`

Answer (score 0):

Just wipe the database with the [Reset Database Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/)